# How to filter whatsapp number from a excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to filter whats app numbers from a excel file(consider file name `a.csv`) and export it with other 2 excel file. 1 with whats app users (filtered from `a.csv`) and another with non whats app users (filtered from `a.csv`)

I want to know how can I do this using JavScript

P.S: I am building a chrome extension which can be used to separate whats app users and non whats app users from a excel file containing their ph no. I am asking what should be my approach

Comment: Please provide some code and explain the issues you have.

Comment: Are you asking how to load a csv file into a web page, process it, then create downloads from that? That's three separate questions basically. For the first part you need an <input type="file">, a change event handler and the FileReader API. The 2nd part is basically splitting the file into a lines array and splitting that into "cells", then checking them for the number cell being blank or not. The third part is creating the two new CSV strings and offering them as downloads

Comment: I am building a chrome extension which can be used to separate whats app users and non whats app users from a excel file containing their ph no. I am asking what should be my approach

Comment: How do you know if a user has WhatsApp installed or not? Show us some code your tried, demo data and where you struggle.

Comment: I don't want to know if the user has installed whats app or not rather I want to know if whats app account exists for that mobile number. There is no code to show because I want to know the approach